# Terraform: Missing required argument

Tags: terraform

Someone can help to clarify how local and global variables working in Terraform ? I'm facing now this issue :

> PS E:\GitRepo\Terraform\prod> terraform plan
> ╷
> │ Error: Missing required argument
> │
> │   on main.tf line 46, in module "pub-rt":
> │   46: module "pub-rt" {
> │
> │ The argument "vpc_cidr_block" is required, but no definition was found.
> ╵
> ╷
> │ Error: Missing required argument
> │
> │   on main.tf line 46, in module "pub-rt":
> │   46: module "pub-rt" {
> │
> │ The argument "nat_id" is required, but no definition was found.

My code structure is :

```
-- Dev
  -- main.tf
-- modules
  -- rt
    -- pub-rt.tf
    -- pri-rt.tf
    -- vars.tf
```

This is my **main.tf**

```
# Create Public Route Table
module "pub-rt" {
  source            = "../modules/rt"
  pub_rt_tag        = { Name = "prod-pub-rt" }
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  ir_cidr           = var.ir_cidr                                 # routing inside the VPC
  gateway_id        = module.igw.igwId                            # routing to the internet through igw
}


# Create Private Route Table
module "pri-rt" {
  source            = "../modules/rt"
  pub_rt_tag        = { Name = "prod-pri-rt" }
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  vpc_cidr_block    = var.vpc_cidr                                # routing inside the VPC
  nat_id            = module.nat.natId                            # routing to the internet NAT
}
```

My ../rt/**vars.tf** contains :

```
variable "vpc_cidr_block" { }  //this variable point to "pri-rt.tf"
variable "vpc_id" { }          //this variable common and point to "pub-rt.tf" and "pri-rt.tf"
variable "gateway_id" { }      //this variable point to "pub-rt.tf"
variable "nat_id" { }          //this variable point to "pri-rt.tf"
variable "ir_cidr" { }         //this variable point to "pub-rt.tf"
```

Comment: You aren't passing the `vpc_cidr_block` in the `pub-rt` module.

Comment: I don't need "vpc_cidr_block" in the "pub-rt". I need it only in "pri-rt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables have module scope, so there is no global variables that propagate over all sub-modules. Your `vars.tf` should be in `./Dev`. You need also corresponding `vars.tf` with variables specific to your module.